# Assert null value in Json response using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

Trying to assert null value in JSON response.
In my below groovy script, it should pass the assert as my `Token` has some value but it gives me error.
I want when Token has null value then it should failed the assert.

```
{
   "ResponseCode": 1,
   "ResponseData": null,
   "Result":    {
      "LoginResult": 2,
      "Token": "244F5F16-EB3B-4A58-A784-AE55BF87EA53",
      "UserInformation": null
   }
}
```

Groovy script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
assert jsonSlurper.Token != null
```

It gives me error:

```
assert jsonSlurper.Token != null | | | | null false [Result:[LoginResult:2, Token:244F5F16-EB3B-4A58-A784-AE55BF87EA53, UserInformation:null], ResponseCode:1, ResponseData:null]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid key path:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
   "ResponseCode": 1,
   "ResponseData": null,
   "Result":    {
      "LoginResult": 2,
      "Token": "244F5F16-EB3B-4A58-A784-AE55BF87EA53",
      "UserInformation": null
   }
}'''

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)
assert jsonSlurper.Result.Token != null
```

It should be: `jsonSlurper.Result.Token`